# Binding a scalar to a sigilless variable (Perl 6)

Tags: raku, variable-binding

Let me start by saying that I understand that what I'm asking about in the title is dubious practice (as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50399784/is-there-a-purpose-or-benefit-in-prohibiting-sigilless-variables-from-rebinding)), but my lack of understanding concerns the syntax involved.

When I first tried to bind a scalar to a sigilless symbol, I did this:

```
my \a = $(3);
```

thinking that `$(...)` would package the Int 3 in a Scalar (as seemingly suggested in the [documentation](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Scalar)), which would then be bound to symbol a. This doesn't seem to work though: the Scalar is nowhere to be found (`a.VAR.WHAT` returns (Int), not (Scalar)).

In the above-referenced post, raiph mentions that the desired binding can be performed using a different syntax:

```
my \a = $ = 3;
```

which works. Given the result, I suspect that the statement can be phrased equivalently, though less concisely, as: `my \a = (my $ = 3)`, which I could then understand.

That leaves the question: why does the attempt with `$(...)` not work, and what does it do instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What `$(…)` does is turn a value into an `item`.
(A value in a scalar variable (`$a`) also gets marked as being an item)

```perl6
say flat (1,2,      (3,4)  );
# (1 2 3 4)

say flat (1,2,    $((3,4)) );
# (1 2 (3 4))

say flat (1,2, item((3,4)) );
# (1 2 (3 4))
```

Basically it is there to prevent a value from flattening. The reason for its existence is that Perl 6 does not flatten lists as much as most other languages, and sometimes you need a little more control over flattening.

---

The following only sort-of does what you want it to do

```perl6
my \a = $ = 3;
```

A bare `$` is an anonymous `state` variable.

```perl6
my \a = (state $) = 3;
```

The problem shows up when you run that same bit of code more than once.

```perl6
sub foo ( $init ) {
  my \a = $ = $init; # my \a = (state $) = $init;

  (^10).map: {
    sleep 0.1;
    ++a
  }
}

.say for await (start foo(0)), (start foo(42));
# (43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52)
# (53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62)

# If foo(42) beat out foo(0) instead it would result in:
# (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)
# (11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20)
```

Note that variable is shared between calls.
The first Promise halts at the `sleep` call, and then the second sets the state variable before the first runs `++a`.

If you use `my $` instead, it now works properly.

```perl6
sub foo ( $init ) {
  my \a = my $ = $init;

  (^10).map: {
    sleep 0.1;
    ++a
  }
}

.say for await (start foo(0)), (start foo(42));
# (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)
# (43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52)
```

---

The thing is that sigiless “*variables*” aren't really variables (they don't vary), they are more akin to lexically scoped (non)constants.

```perl6
constant \foo = (1..10).pick; # only pick one value and never change it

say foo;
```

```perl6
for ^5 {
  my \foo = (1..10).pick;     # pick a new one each time through

  say foo;
}
```

Basically the whole point of them is to be as close as possible to referring to the value you assign to it. [(Static Single Assignment)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_single_assignment_form)

```perl6
# these work basically the same
-> \a        {…}
-> \a is raw {…}
-> $a is raw {…}

# as do these
my \a  = $i;
my \a := $i;
my $a := $i;
```

---

Note that above I wrote the following:

```perl6
my \a = (state $) = 3;
```

Normally in the declaration of a state var, the assignment only happens the first time the code gets run. Bare `$` doesn't have a declaration as such, so I had to prevent that behaviour by putting the declaration in parens.

```perl6
# bare $
for (5 ... 1) {
  my \a =        $  = $_; # set each time through the loop

  say a *= 2; # 15 12 9 6 3
}

# state in parens
for (5 ... 1) {
  my \a = (state $) = $_; # set each time through the loop

  say a *= 2; # 15 12 9 6 3
}

# normal state declaration
for (5 ... 1) {
  my \a =  state $  = $_; # set it only on the first time through the loop

  say a *= 2; # 15 45 135 405 1215
}
```

Comment: Awesome answer! Clarified some of my misconceptions, and gave me more to think about. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[Sigilless variables are not actually variables, they are more of an alias](https://docs.perl6.org/language/glossary#index-entry-Sigilless_Variable), that is, they are not [containers](https://docs.perl6.org/language/containers) but bind to the values they get on the right hand side.

```
my \a = $(3); 
say a.WHAT; # OUTPUT: «(Int)␤»
say a.VAR.WHAT; # OUTPUT: «(Int)␤»
```

Here, by doing $(3) you are actually putting in scalar context what is already in scalar context:

```
my \a = 3; say a.WHAT; say a.VAR.WHAT; # OUTPUT: «(Int)␤(Int)␤»
```

However, the second form in your question does something different. You're binding to an anonymous variable, which is a container:

```
my \a = $ = 3; 
say a.WHAT;    # OUTPUT: «(Int)␤»
say a.VAR.WHAT;# OUTPUT: «(Scalar)␤»
```

In the first case, `a` was an alias for 3 (or `$(3)`, which is the same); in the second, `a` is an alias for `$`, which is a container, whose value is `3`. This last case is equivalent to:

```
 my $anon = 3; say $anon.WHAT; say $anon.VAR.WHAT; # OUTPUT: «(Int)␤(Scalar)␤»
```

(If you have some suggestion on how to improve the documentation, I'd be happy to follow up on it)

Comment: Hi jjmerelo: I understand your entire answer, except for the part that I think is crucial: the part where you mention that `$(...)` puts the Int in a "scalar context". The docs say "A literal Scalar may be placed around a literal value by enclosing the value in $(…)." Obviously, that doesn't mean what I thought it did; but it doesn't talk about "scalar context" either. When I search for the meaning of the term "context", I find no clear definition, and it seems I'm [not alone](https://github.com/perl6/doc/issues/1225). So I still have difficulty understanding what it is that `$(...)` does.

Comment: @Ozzy I'm still working on that issue. Takes some time. Anyway, my point was that putting a `$()` around a literal does not create a container, which was maybe what you were looking of.