# Useless use of hash composer, or cannot modify an immutable hash?

Tags: raku

This code:

```
constant %what = { doesn't => 'change' }; 
%what = { will => "change" }
```

Should say something along the lines of "Cannot modify an immutable hash". However, it says:

```
Potential difficulties:
Useless use of hash composer on right side of hash assignment; did you mean := instead?
```

Positionals have pretty much the same problem, but the error is different. In this case it's about cannot modify an immutable, but an Str:

```
constant @what = <does not change>;
@what = <does change> # Cannot modify an immutable Str (does)
```

A Scalar works as expected. Is this a case of LTA error message, or is some container magic at work here that I'm missing?

Comment: Feels like some pre-GLR leftover to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> This code:

```
constant %what = { doesn't => 'change' }; 
%what = { will => "change" }
```

> Should say something along the lines of "Cannot modify an immutable hash".

Who says so? I mean this rhetorically, not rudely. I get *why* you think so but it's important to be careful with use of the word "should" because it implies some authority says so, eg the specification, or a design document, or someone's common sense, or whatever.

---

Per the current spec, and Rakudo implementation, what `constant foo ...` does is permanently (constantly) *bind* `foo` to some particular "value".

If that "value" is a container, then `foo` constantly refers to that container. (Yes, a container can be a "value", for some definition of "value" that is appropriate here.)

So your code above has changed the elements contained *within* that container, and that is, per spec, perfectly cromulent:

```
say %what; # {will => change}
```

In the meantime, the warning message legitimately mentions useless use of a hash constructor, plus it notes:

```
did you mean := instead?
```

If you try that:

```
constant %what = { doesn't => 'change' }; 
%what := { will => "change" }
```

You get:

```
Cannot use bind operator with this left-hand side
```

Because, as already established, `%what` is a compile time constant *permanently* bound to a hash created and initialized at compile time and that aspect -- the permanent binding of `%what` to that particular hash -- can't be changed during this program run.

> `Positional`s have pretty much the same problem, but the error is different. In this case it's about cannot modify an immutable, but an `Str`:

```
constant @what = <does not change>;
@what = <does change> # Cannot modify an immutable Str (does)
```

That's a bit different. A `constant` declaration binds, regardless of whether you write `=` or `:=`. So the constant declarations are equivalent to:

```
constant %what := { doesn't => 'change' }
constant @what := <does not change>;
```

The first line binds `%what` to `{ doesn't => 'change' }` which is a mutable `Hash`.

The second line binds `@what` to `<does not change>` which is an immutable `List`.

You could instead write:

```
constant @what = [<does not change>];
@what = <does change>;
say @what; # [does change]
```

> A `Scalar` works as expected.

Not quite.

A *scalar* (lowercase, the generic term) does:

```
constant $scalar = 42;
$scalar = 99; # Cannot assign to an immutable value
```

Remembering that `constant` always *binds*, the above code parallels:

```
my $scalar := 42;
$scalar = 99; # Cannot assign to an immutable value
```

But a [`Scalar`](https://docs.raku.org/type/Scalar) works the same as the other containers in this context:

```
constant $scalar = $ = 42;
$scalar = 99; # OK
```

(Don't write code like that unless you want to annoy people.)

> Is this a case of LTA error message, or is some container magic at work?

That's a good question, and one I'm not going to try answer.