# What's the benefit of assigning non-scalars to scalars?

Tags: raku, sigils

I sometimes see code that (to me) uses the wrong sigil in front of the variable

```
my $arr  = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];      # an array
my $lst  = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5);      # a list
my $hash = {a => '1', b => '2'}; # a hash
my $func = -> $foo { say $foo }; # a callable
```

And it all just works exactly as expected

```
say $arr[0];    # 1
say $lst[1];    # 2
say $hash<a>;   # 1
say $hash{'b'}; # 2
$func('hello'); # hello
```

### Q1: What are the benefits of using the scalar container for this, rather than just using the 'correct' one?

I know that Perl only let collections store scalars, requiring things like multi-dimensional arrays be done via array references, with `[...]` and `{...}` being array and hash *reference* literals respectively.

To expand and clarify what I mean here, there's *basically* two ways to define things, by value and by reference:

```perl
# "values"
my @arr = (1, 2, 3, 4);
my %hash = (1 => 2, 3 => 4); 

# which are accessed like this:
my $result1 = $arr[0];
my $result2 = $hash{1};

# references (note how the braces canged)
my $aref = [1, 2, 3, 4];
my $href = {1 => 2, 3 => 4};

# or making a reference to existing collections
my $aref2 = \@arr;
my $href2 = \%hash;

# which are accessed like this:
my $result3 = $aref->[0];
my $result4 = $href->{1};
```

The reasoning behind this madness is that Perl collections only really accept scalars, and references are just that.
Using references is essentially a way to enable multidimensional arrays.

TL;DR, the distinction makes sense in Perl because they serve two distinctly different purposes.

### Q2: Are we dealing with Perl 5-like reference literals again, or is something else at play?

Comment: "To expand and clarify what I mean here, there's basically two ways to define things, by value and by reference" Isn't that basically true of all programming, from assembler on up? It's direct or indirect. At the machine level you're either talking about some bits, or some bits that are a memory location that contains some bits. At a mid-level it's pointers. At a high level it's a value, or a reference. Isn't it the same in all programming languages, even if they do like to use differing terminology, wrap it up in differing types, and so forth?

Comment: @raiph Sure, but this is about language constructs. The Perl family of languages could just as well have hidden all this information and made it completely opaque to the user (like Python), where references and values are accessed and used indistinguishably from each other. But Perl 5 makes a clear distinction between the two, and it appears to me vestiges of this old syntax still exist in its sister language without the same underlying semantics.

Comment: Imo Raku makes a *much* clearer distinction between these two, but also makes it *much* easier to remove the distinction where the distinction doesn't matter or gets in the way. Imo the Perl design in this respect has some advantages and disadvantages relative to Python. Imo Raku generally retains the advantages while dissolving the disadvantages. Also, of those who use both Raku and Perl (clearly a self-selected group of folk who see value in using Raku for some things instead of Perl), the clearing up of this aspect is generally talked of as a strength. YMMV.

Comment: I don't know, I'm still a newbie at both Perls. That's why I gotta ask all the dumb questions :P

Comment: I am, as may be obvious, enjoying your questions, and think they're good ones. (That said, I'm *still* more than reeling from the implications of the ratchet bug. My left hemisphere has always considered anything other than a pure math driven approach to programming, from top to bottom, to be asking for trouble, and grumbles about any deviation. In the meantime my right hemisphere loves Raku, but worries about the balance between the upsides and downsides of roasting and toasting [cheese](http://blogs.perl.org/users/zoffix_znet/2018/02/perl-6-on-specs-versioning-changes-and-breakage.html).)

Comment: Whereas I'm a total type theory nut, I always like tinkering with programming languages, especially if they do interesting things with their type system, which Raku thankfully does.
I was THIS close writing my master's thesis about what I then called "predicate oriented programming", which is essentially Raku's `subset` declarations, except extended to be the basis of the entire type system.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215187/discussion-between-raiph-and-electric-coffee).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**TL;DR** For computers, and humans, and therefore Raku too, a non-scalar (plural thing) is also a scalar (singular thing). (Whereas the converse may not be true.) For example, an `Array` is both a plural thing (an array of elements) and a *single* thing, an `Array`. When you wish to syntactically and statically emphasize a datum's most generic singular nature, use `$`.

Here's an opening example based on @sid_com++'s comment:

```
my @a = ( 1, 2 ), 42, { :a, :b }
for @a -> $b {say $b}            # (1 2)␤42␤{a => True, b => True}␤ 
for @a -> @b {say @b}            # (1 2)␤Type check failed ...
```

The first loop binds values to `$b`. It is "fault tolerant" because it accepts *any* value. The second loop binds to `@b`. Any value that doesn't do the `Positional` role leads to a type check failure.

## My Raku equivalent of your Perl code

Here's a Raku translation of your Perl code:

```
my @arr = (1, 2, 3, 4);
my %hash = (1 => 2, 3 => 4); 

my $result1 = @arr[0];                          # <-- Invariant sigil
my $result2 = %hash{1};                         # <-- Invariant sigil

my $aref = [1, 2, 3, 4];
my $href = {1 => 2, 3 => 4};

my $aref2 = @arr;                               # <-- Drop `\`
my $href2 = %hash;                              # <-- Drop `\`

my $result3 = $aref[0];                         # <-- Drop `->`
my $result4 = $href{1};                         # <-- Drop `->`
```

The code is a little shorter. Idiomatic code would probably be a good bit shorter still, dropping:

- The `ref` variables. A variable `@foo` *is* a reference. A `[...]` in term (noun) position *is* an `Array` reference literal. There's little or no need to use scalar variables to *explicitly* store references.
- The parens in the first couple lines;
- Semi colons after most closing braces that are the last code on a line;

Raku's sigils are invariant. Here are [two tables providing an at-a-glance comparison of Perl's sigil variation vs Raku's sigil invariance](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nq2HkAYbG5o&t=10m18s).

## Why bother with sigils?

All the sigil variations directly correspond to embedding "type" info into an identifier's name that's visible to humans, the language, and the compiler:

- **foo** Tells Raku features which pick between a singular and plural way of operating on data should decide based on the run-time type of the data.
- **`$foo`** Tells Raku to pick singular behavior. A value might be, say, a `List` containing many values, but its singular nature is being emphasized instead.
- **`&foo`** Type checks that a bound or assigned value does the [`Callable`](https://docs.raku.org/type/Callable) role.
- **`@foo`** Tells Raku to pick [`Iterable`](https://docs.raku.org/type/Iterable) behavior. Also type checks that bound values do the [`Positional`](https://docs.raku.org/type/Positional) role. A `List` or `Array` can be bound, but trying to bind to `42` or a `Hash` will yield a type error.
- **`%foo`** Tells Raku to pick `Iterable` behavior. Also type checks that bound values do the [`Associative`](https://docs.raku.org/type/Associative) role. A `Pair` or `Bag` can be bound, but trying to bind to `42` or a `List` will yield a type error.

I'll next consider your question for each sigil alternative.

## Slashing out sigils

Repeating your examples, but this time "slashing out" sigils:

```
my \arr  = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];      # an array
my \lst  = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5);      # a list
my \hash = {a => '1', b => '2'}; # a hash
my \func = -> \foo { say foo };  # a callable
```

These *almost* just work exactly as expected:

```
say arr[0];     # 1
say lst[1];     # 2
say hash<a>;    # 1
say hash{'b'};  # 2
func.('hello'); # hello
```

See the `$ vs &` below for why it's `func.(...)` not just `func(...)`. This last nosigil case is of little consequence because in Raku one normally writes:

```
sub func (\foo) { say foo }
func('hello'); # hello
```

Identifiers with their sigils slashed out are [SSA form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_single_assignment_form). That is to say, they are permanently bound, once, at compile-time, to their data. Value type data is immutable. A reference is also immutable (although the data it refers to can change), so for example, if it's an array, it will remain the same array.

(See [**Is there a purpose or benefit in prohibiting sigilless variables from rebinding?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50399784/is-there-a-purpose-or-benefit-in-prohibiting-sigilless-variables-from-rebinding) for further discussion.)

## `$foo` instead of `@foo`?

Raku supports:

- Lazy lists. (This can be *very* useful.)
- A boolean `.is-lazy` method that indicates whether list assignment (`@foo = ...`) should treat an assigned object as lazy or eager. Importantly, a lazy list is allowed to return `False`. (This too can be *very* useful.)
- Infinite lazy lists. (Yet another thing that can be *very* useful.)

The above three features are individually useful, and can be useful together. But while it is appropriate that Raku doesn't try to police these features other than the way it does, one needs to follow rules to avoid problems. And the simplest way to do that is to use the right sigil when it matters, as explained next.

Let's say `infinite` is an infinite lazy list that returns `False` for `.is-lazy`:

```
my $foo = infinite;
say $foo[10];        # displays 11th element
my @foo = infinite;
```

The first two lines work fine. The third hangs, trying to copy an infinite number of elements into `@foo`.

---

Is it one thing or many things? Of course, if it's a list, it's both:

```
my $list = <a b c> ;
my @list = <a b c> ;
my \list = <a b c> ;
.say for $list ;      # (a b c)␤   <-- Treat as one thing
.say for @list ;      # a␤b␤c␤    <-- Treat as plural thing
.say for  list ;      # a␤b␤c␤    <-- Go by bound value, not sigil
```

The choice of sigil in the above just indicates what view you want language constructs and readers to take *by default*. You can reverse yourself if you wish:

```
.say for @$list ;     # a␤b␤c␤
.say for $@list ;     # [a b c]␤
.say for $(list)      # (a b c)␤
```

---

Assignment is different:

```
my ($numbers, $letters) = (1, 2, 3), ('a', 'b', 'c');
say $numbers;                                            # (1 2 3)
say $letters;                                            # (a b c)
my (@numbers, @letters) = (1, 2, 3), ('a', 'b', 'c');
say @numbers;                                            # [(1 2 3) (a b c)]
say @letters;                                            # []
```

Assignment to an `@` variable "slurps" all remaining arguments. (Binding with `:=` and metaops like `Z=` invoke scalar semantics, i.e. don't slurp.)

We see another difference here; assigning to a `$` variable is going to keep a `List` a `List`, but assigning to an `@` variable "slurps" its values *into* whatever container the `@` variable is bound to (by default, an `Array`).

---

A tiny thing is string interpolation:

```
my $list := 1, 2;
my @list := 1, 2;
say "\$list = $list; \@list = @list"; # $list = 1 2; @list = @list
say "@list @list[] @list[1]";         # @list 1 2 2
```

## `$foo` instead of `%foo`?

Again, is it one thing or many things? If it's a hash, it's both.

```
my $hash = { :a, :b }
my %hash =   :a, :b ;
my \hash = { :a, :b }
.say for $hash ;      # {a => True, b => True}␤   <-- By sorted keys
.say for %hash ;      # {b => True}␤{a => True}␤  <-- Random order
.say for  hash ;      # {a => True}␤{b => True}␤  <-- Random order
```

---

Assignment and string interpolation are also different in a manner analogous to `@`.

## `$foo` instead of `&foo`?

This section is just for completeness. It only shows one reason to use `$`. And I've just made it up for this answer -- I don't recall seeing anyone using it.

As with the other sigil alternatives, the primary difference would be whether you do or don't want to emphasize the `Callable` nature of a callable.

As the setup, note that a `sub` declaration in Raku declares a corresponding constant identifier with an `&` sigil:

```
sub foo (--> Int) { 42 }
say foo;                     # 42
say &foo.signature;          # ( --> Int)
&foo = 99;                   # Cannot modify an immutable Sub...
```

Which means that if you declare a mutable routine variable with the `&` sigil you can call it *without* the sigil:

```
my &bar = { 99 }
say bar;                     # 99
&bar = { 100 }
say bar;                     # 100
```

If you wanted to declare a mutable routine variable and *not* allow it to be easily called without a sigil you could declare it with `$` instead:

```
my Callable $baz = { 101 }
say baz;                     # Undeclared routine: baz
say $baz();                  # 101   <-- Need both sigil and parens
```

Btw, this is why you get:

```
my \func = -> \foo { say foo }
func('hello');  # Variable '&func' is not declared
```

## Reference literals

> Q2: Are we dealing with Perl 5-like reference literals again, or is something else at play?

Despite your examples, knowing Perl (at least I did last century), and pondering what you've written, I'm still unclear what you're asking.

A wide range of programming languages adopt `[...]` in term (noun) position as a reference to a literal array. There are other common conventions for other data structure literals. This is what Raku does.

Thus one can write:

```
my $structure =
[ 0, [ 99, [ ( 1, 2, 3), { key => [ 4, 5, | < a b >, c => 42 ] } ], ], ] ;

say $structure[1][1][1]<key>[4]<c> ; # 42
```

Is that the sort of thing you're talking about?

## Dereference literals

`postcircumfix:< [ ] >` is declared as a pile of multi subs that (are supposed to) apply a `Positional` consistent indexing protocol on their left argument.

- All built in types that do the `Positional` role work.
- User defined types that do the `Positional` role *should* work because the role defines typed interface stubs that must be implemented by types that do the role.
- But ducktyping is also OK; provided a type implements the basics of the interface `postcircumfix:< [ ] >` it should work.

The same story applies for `postcircumfix:< { } >` and `postcircumfix:« < > »`, but the relevant role/protocol is `Associative` consistent indexing.

And a similar story applies for `postcircumfix:< ( ) >` and `Callable`.

Comment: The second for loop dies: `my @a=(1,2),Any,(5,6); for @a -> $b {say $b}; for @a -> @b {say @b}; say "Hello";`

Comment: No, I'm not talking about the postcircumfix operator, but the circumfix operator.
In Perl5, the main difference between `(1, 2, 3)` and `[1, 2, 3]` is that the first is an array and the second is a _reference to_ an array.
`@arr = (1, 2, 3);` vs `$aref = [1, 2, 3]` because references are scalar.
Same with hashes: `%hash = ('a' => 1, 'b' => 2);` vs `$href = {'a' => 1, 'b' => 2};`
`$aref` and `$href`, being scalar, need to be de-referenced to be used.

Comment: ElectricCoffee: in Raku, `( )` is just a grouping syntax, such that `(3)` is not a list.  What creates the list is the chained infix listop `,` (if you want a single item list, you use `(3,)` or even just `3,`, or you can assign `3` to a `@`-sigiled var).  There is a circumfix operator `[ ]`  that creates an array — it just happens to be constructed from the list made by `, `.

Comment: @raiph the biggest difference in Perl in terms of notation is that `((1, 2), (3, 4))` produces `(1, 2, 3, 4)` and `([1, 2], [3, 4])` doesn't due to the scalar nature of `[]` vs the non-scalar nature of `()`.

Comment: Instead of having just one way to "slurp" (flatten), Raku supports several ways. It can mimic Perl's way, turning `((1, 2), (3, 4))` and `([1,2],[3,4])` into `(1, 2, 3, 4)` and `[1,2],[3,4]` respectively, or retain the structure in *both* cases, turning them into `(1,2),(3,4)` and `[1,2],[3,4]`.

Answer (score 5):

Some great answers already! For even further interesting reading on this general topic, may I suggest [Day 2 – Perl 6: Sigils, Variables, and Containers](https://perl6advent.wordpress.com/2017/12/02/perl-6-sigils-variables-and-containers/) ? It helped me to understand some of the related topics such as scalars as containers and the *decont* op `<>`. I think the examples may give a bit more rationale on the interplay of `$` and `@`/`%` to manage the subtleties of efficiently packing/unpacking data structures as intended.

Comment: Honestly a great page! It cleared up a lot of things!