# Should sigilless "variables" with type constraints be re-bindable?

Tags: immutability, raku, rakudo, variable-binding

[**EDIT**: closed in favor of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69231506/what-are-the-rules-for-re-binding, which I formulated after more clearly understanding what I was trying to ask in this question.]

My understanding from [Is there a purpose or benefit in prohibiting sigilless variables from rebinding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50399784/is-there-a-purpose-or-benefit-in-prohibiting-sigilless-variables-from-rebinding/50401989#50401989) was a symbol declared without a sigil could *never* be rebound.  Quoting from that answer:

> Yes, [the current behavior is] certainly by design, and - like most things in [Raku] design - it's this way for more than one reason.… It was decided to make the sigilless symbol form a "static single assignment" syntax…. There were various reasons for this, including… enhancing program readability by having **a form that lets the reader know that the symbol will never be rebound to a new value**

(emphasis added.)

Given that, I was very surprised to see by the code below:

```
my Int \b = 8;
say "{b*b}"; # OUTPUT: «64»

b := 4;
say "{b*b}"; # OUTPUT: «16»
```

That is, when `b` is declared without a sigil but *with* an `Int` type constraint, it can be rebound – unlike when it lacks that type constraint.  Is this behavior a bug, or is it correct?

If it is, how does it fit in with the design considerations mentioned in the answer linked above?

(See also [this Raku/doc issue thread](https://github.com/Raku/doc/issues/3950#issuecomment-912726932) on GitHub for a discussion of this behavior and whether it's intentional.)

Comment: cf [a comment I wrote discussing some of the darker truths about [the Satanic Sons of Beelzebub](https://www.reddit.com/r/rakulang/comments/kdq9uk/differences_between_sigilless_and_sigilled/gg6u8ll/): "Sigilless variables ... appear to be, at least in a PL and/or compiler maturity sense, second class citizens. ... sigilless variables are not (yet?) as clean as SSAs, and so SSB begins to take on a grade B rather than grade A aspect". Right now what you've shown in this Q smashed my mental model, even of SSBs let alone SSAs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bug.

[no language should **sometimes** prohibit sigilless variables from rebinding depending on whether a or which type is specified in the declaration].